# checking class not returning true

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my `#pax` div has class named `.is-show` I made function to check with if statement but it doesn't work any help will be appericated.

```js
function yle() {
  var le = document.querySelector("#pax");
  if (le.classList.contains("is-shown")) {
    alert("hello");
  }
}
yle();
```

```html
<div id="pax" class="p-section--03 is-shown">
```

Comment: You did not close your `div` tag. Also make sure your script runs *after* the document has loaded. Check for errors in the console (F12)

Answer (score 0):

You should add your script tag after the DOM elements, this may be a cause where DOM is not loaded and your script is running first, Hence unable to find your elements.

```
<html>
<div id="pax" class="p-section--03 is-shown"></div>
<script>
    function yle() {
      var le = document.querySelector("#pax");  
      if (le.classList.contains("is-shown")) {
        alert("hello");
      }
    }
yle();
</script>
</html>
```

Else everything is fine, Thanks.